# How to embed google trend chart in html?

Tags: javascript, html, google-trends

I saw a site that embedded an interactive Google trend chart on the page: http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/danbo

When I inspected the element, the chart was embedded with the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/trends/embed.js?hl=en-US&amp;q=danbo%20robot,danbo%20amazon,danbo%20yotsuba&amp;content=1&amp;cid=TIMESERIES_GRAPH_0&amp;export=5&amp;w=600&amp;h=350"></script>
```

I checked the top of the html for google related script and I found these:

```
<script> (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){ (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o), m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m) })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga'); ga('create', 'UA-15176568-9'); ga('send', 'pageview'); </script>

<script type="text/javascript"> var googletag = googletag || {}; googletag.cmd = googletag.cmd || []; (function() { var gads = document.createElement('script'); gads.async = true; gads.type = 'text/javascript'; gads.src = 'http://www.googletagservices.com/tag/js/gpt.js'; var node = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; node.parentNode.insertBefore(gads, node); })(); googletag.cmd.push(function() { googletag.pubads().setTargeting('site', 'kym'); googletag.pubads().setTargeting('page', '_memes_danbo'); }); </script>
```

But when i created an html file as such:

```
<html>

<script> (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){ (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o), m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m) })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga'); ga('create', 'UA-15176568-9'); ga('send', 'pageview'); </script>

<script type="text/javascript"> var googletag = googletag || {}; googletag.cmd = googletag.cmd || []; (function() { var gads = document.createElement('script'); gads.async = true; gads.type = 'text/javascript'; gads.src = 'http://www.googletagservices.com/tag/js/gpt.js'; var node = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; node.parentNode.insertBefore(gads, node); })(); googletag.cmd.push(function() { googletag.pubads().setTargeting('site', 'kym'); googletag.pubads().setTargeting('page', '_memes_danbo'); }); </script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/trends/embed.js?hl=en-US&amp;q=danbo%20robot,danbo%20amazon,danbo%20yotsuba&amp;content=1&amp;cid=TIMESERIES_GRAPH_0&amp;export=5&amp;w=600&amp;h=350"></script>

</html>
```

I did not have the Google trend chart but I didn't get the chart and had this:

[image]

When you go to the Google trend site, e.g. http://www.google.com/trends/explore?hl=en-US#q=danbo+robot,danbo+amazon,danbo+yotsuba , there are embedded scripts that one can copy and paste into the html but when i put it in my own html it didn't work too.

**How do I embed an interactive Google trend chart like at the end of this webpage**  http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/danbo ?

Comment: Actually, [it works](http://jsfiddle.net/8nu2vwbe/). Did you put your code directly in `<html>` tag? It's better to obey structure `html > head + body`.

Comment: When i ran open the html file locally with internet conenction, i get `The file or directory could not be found.`instead of the chart.

Comment: Problem is inside code which script downloads from google server: `document.write('<iframe width="600" height="350" src="//www.google.com/trends/fetchComponent?hl\75en-US\46q\75danbo%20robot,danbo%20amazon,danbo%20yotsuba\46content\0751\46cid\75TIMESERIES_GRAPH_0\46export\0755\46w\075600\46h\075350" style="border: none;"></iframe>');` This part: `src="//` tell browser to open iframe via same protocol that main page uses. This protocol is **file:** in your case, and obviously you don't have such path on your HDD. You should use local server to serve your page via **http:**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Include the Google trend result in an iframe and you are done.

```
<iframe scrolling="no" style="border:none;" width="640" height="330" src="http://www.google.com/trends/fetchComponent?hl=en-US&q=danbo+robot,danbo+amazon,danbo+yotsuba &cmpt=q&content=1&cid=TIMESERIES_GRAPH_0&export=5&w=640&h=330"></iframe>
```

See [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jf8t9adh/)