# why can't I embed a google trends chart?

Tags: javascript, html, embed, google-trends

here is a trends search for the world "google": https://trends.google.com/trends/explore?q=google&geo=US

i want to embed this into my jekyll website, so i paste the embed code into my markdown file:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ssl.gstatic.com/trends_nrtr/2213_RC01/embed_loader.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  trends.embed.renderExploreWidget("TIMESERIES", {
    "comparisonItem": [{
      "keyword": "google",
      "geo": "US",
      "time": "today 12-m"
    }],
    "category": 0,
    "property": ""
  }, {
    "exploreQuery": "q=google&geo=US&date=today 12-m",
    "guestPath": "https://trends.google.com:443/trends/embed/"
  });

</script>
```

but the chart does not appear. same if i copy-paste into the html of a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/26y4qkba/). some [old posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27028132/how-to-embed-google-trend-chart-in-html) tell you to use an iframe, but their solutions don't render.

what am i doing wrong?

Comment: I try this and it works. Maybe this can be dependent from specific browser. Maybe you can see some error logs in console or network tab?

Comment: yeah i just realized it only works in chrome, not safari, but i have no idea why

Answer (score 0):

this is an xframes issue (see [related post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27358966/how-to-set-x-frame-options-on-iframe)). the embedded chart renders fine in chrome, but in safari it throws the error:

> Refused to display [url] in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'.

from what i understand this is a safari issue, and there is nothing you can do.